# Trigger D3 update pattern on button click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to use buttons to trigger D3's update loop but am not sure how to do this. I would like the first button to update with data labelled "championsleague" and the second to update with "premierleague".

This is what I've tried so far

```
<button class="opts" value="championsleague">Champions League</button>
<button class="opts" value="premierleague">Premier League</button>

// handle on click event
d3.select('.opts')
  .on('click', function() {
    var data = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
    updateLegend(data);
  })
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwg7mf8f/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `d3.select()` which only selects the first element. You need to `selectAll` the buttons with the specified class `opts`.

Check this snippet

```
d3.selectAll('.opts')
  .on('click', function() {
    var data = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
    updateLegend(data);
  });
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwg7mf8f/7/)